# strcmp() not returning 0 when strings are equal

Tags: c, return, compare, getline

I have seen similar questions but none of them have helped me. I am wanting to check if user input is equal to "q" and if it is then quit from the program but 0 is never returned.

I have seen that the string needs to be terminated with a NULL (\0) value but I don't know how I could do this in the way I am working. I have the following:

```
char *input = "\0";

linelen = getline(&input,&len,stdin);
        if(strcmp(input, "q")==0)
        {
            return;
        }
```

My problem is that I really want to be using getline if possible because it works quite well for what I need to do and if I change input to char *input[2] I can't use getline without causing problems.

(When I type q into the program it returns 10. Also, I am quite new with C so sorry for any stupid mistakes.)

EDIT: I got the result of 10 when doing the following:

```
int j = strcmp(input, "q");
printf("%d", j);

INPUT:
q
OUTPUT:
10
```

Comment: I'll make it more clear. One minute please

Comment: Your question is written up badly, we have to guess what the code does that you don't show us. Please (re)read the help text that explains you how to ask a question here. For the question itself, `getline` also reads the terminating `'\n'` character into the buffer, so no wonder that the two strings don't agree. Just check for `input[0] == 'q'`. Also no need to assign a string literal to `input` before doing `getline`. If you want to initialize it (a good idea) use `0`, instead.

Answer (score 1):

`getline` reads a line from the input **INCLUDING THE NEWLINE ON THE END OF THE LINE**.  So your input of `q` is actually the string `"q\n"`, which is not the same as `"q"` and so compares as different.